# JavaScript : Maximum value in textbox asp.net on IE10

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have problem about this code in IE10. I want Textbox accept only number maximum value 100 but **IE 10 has error message on textbox "You must enter text with 3 or fewer characters"** in 
 Please help me. Thank you

```
 <%-- for Maximum and minimum values in a textbox--%>
            function minmax(value, min, max) {
                if (parseInt(value) < min || isNaN(parseInt(value)))
                    return 0;
                else if (parseInt(value) > max)
                    return 100;
                else return value;
            }
//Here is asp.net Textbox
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRetentionRate" runat="server" MaxLength="3" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 100)"></asp:TextBox>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOgTo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to `MaxLength="3"`. I think, you set it for integer and now user inputs OR any function returning value in double OR float. You need to either remove `MaxLength="3"` OR change it to `MaxLength="5"`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have an idea from you. Now it's working fine. I remove MaxLength from my Textbox.
 Yes! I  have another JavaScript for return number to value in double or float  so MaxLength is not necessary.

Comment: You are welcome. Hope my answer was useful to you. Please upvote or mark as an answer so other also can use it for same error.